# Julia shell mode for emacs, not showing prompt or greek letters

Tags: emacs, julia

Using Emacs 24.5.1 x64 on Windows 7, Julia 0.5.0, julia-mode-20170607.537, and julia-shell-20161125.1110

It appears that julia-mode works fine, as I get syntax highlighting and I can do `\delta <tab>` and it shows a Greek delta.

However running the Julia shell from within Emacs is problematic.  After running the [instructions](https://github.com/dennisog/julia-shell-mode) and putting the requested several lines in my `init.el`, I get only a partially running shell.

When I do `M-x run-julia`, the shell starts up and I can do stuff like `2+2`, but there is no `julia>` prompt, no tab completion, no color highlighting, no help when I type a question mark, and an error when I try `\delta <tab>`.

In fact, when I try `\delta <tab>`, the minibuffer says `Search failed: " julia> "`, as though the prompt is "in there" somewhere.

When I'm in a Julia buffer and I do `<C-c> <C-c>`, the minibuffer tells me `Julia shell is busy!` even though nothing is happening in the evidently-crippled shell.

I was also wondering what `julia-shell-mode` is, which is required-in, since that appears to be the name of the package, but I get the following error in my `*messages*` buffer:
`File mode specification error: (file-error "Cannot open load file" "no such file or directory" "julia-shell-mode")`

These are the relevant portions of my init.el, copied straight from the [instructions](https://github.com/dennisog/julia-shell-mode).

```
(defun my-julia-mode-hooks ()
  (require 'julia-shell-mode))
(add-to-list 'load-path "~/.emacs.d/elpa/julia-shell-20161125.1110")
(require 'julia-shell)
(add-hook 'julia-mode-hook 'my-julia-mode-hooks)
(define-key julia-mode-map (kbd "C-c C-c") 'julia-shell-run-region-or-line)
(define-key julia-mode-map (kbd "C-c C-s") 'julia-shell-save-and-go)
```

Any help is much appreciated, as I've given up an Juno/Atom (too slow, hangs), so this is my next option for an editor with Greek letters and an interactive REPL.

Answer (score 1):

The default terminal in emacs is not fully functional. Try `M-x ansi-term`.

Comment: Thanks.  I tried this both before and after doing `run-julia`.  It asks to confirm `cmdproxy.exe`, I hit `<enter>`, then it says `Spawning child process: Invalid argument`